# ${a^2}{\mid}({b^3} + 1)\;$and$\;{b^2}{\mid}({a^3} + 1)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that there are no integers $a,b \gt 2$ such that
 $a^2{\mid}(b^3 + 1)$ and $b^2{\mid}(a^3 + 1)$.

Comment: What have you done to prove this?

Comment: I am not a school student.

Comment: I am not saying that you did this for homework but asked it to enlighten you on where you went wrong or which method might have been better. I am sorry if you found any of what I said demeaning.

Comment: Jafar, put this a different way...Where, exactly, are you getting these problems?

Comment: In particular, was there a typo in your previous question, which should have asked for factors of $x^4-x^3+3x^2+3x+54$ (comes out nicely) rather than $x^4-x^3+3x^2+3x+5$ (pretty much impossible by hand)

Comment: There's [a solution here on AoPS.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h1566613_prove_that_there_are_none_positive_integers)

Answer (score 2):

The counterexample $a=2,\,b=3$ ($4|28,\,9|9$) proves this isn't true.

Addendum for the new problem:

We have $a^2b^2|a^3+b^3+1$ and can replace $|$ with $\le$. Then $(a^2-b)(b^2-a)=a^2b^2-a^3-b^3+ab\le ab+1$, and without loss of generality $a\le b$ so $a^2\le b^2\le a^3+1< a^4$ implies $a^2>b$. Thus we have factorised a positive integer that is $\le ab+1$, each factor being positive. Then $b^2-a\le ab+1$ and $0\le b(b-a)\le a+1\le b+1$, and $b-a<1+\frac{1}{b}<2$. Hence $a=b$ or $a=b-1$. My guess is cheking these cases in turn shows we can't solve with $a\ge 3$.

Comment: Thanks, I have a typo:$a,b > 2$