# Prove that there aren't any positive integers $a,b>2$ such that $a^2 \vert b^3+1$ and $b^2 \vert a^3+1$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I need help with the proof of this number theory question.
$a|b$ means that $a$ divides $ b$, for example $2|10$.

At first, I tried to use algebraic identities and converted $a^3 + 1$ to $(a+1)(a^2 - a + 1)$ and same for the other one, after that I tried to combine the two equations, but I got no where.

Comment: The question has been modified. Is this what you intended to ask ?

Comment: @sathvik Yeah that was great and correct edit thanks for that and i am sorry that i had that mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [${a^2}{\mid}({b^3} + 1)\;$and$\;{b^2}{\mid}({a^3} + 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584453/a2-midb3-1-and-b2-mida3-1). Note a comment there states this has been solved at [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h1566613_prove_that_there_are_none_positive_integers).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\exists$ a prime $p$ s.t. $p|a$ and $p|b$. This means $p|b^3$ and $p|a^2 \Rightarrow p|b^3+1 \Rightarrow p|1$. Hence, $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Now, $b^3 \equiv (-1) \pmod{a^2} \Rightarrow b^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{a^2}$. Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $\phi(a^2)|6 \Rightarrow a(a-1)|6 \Rightarrow a=2$ or $3$. Substituting in original, if $a=2$ then $4|(b^3+1)$ and $b^2|9 \Rightarrow b=3$. Similarly, for $a=3 \Rightarrow b=2$.

Hence, all the solutions are $(a,b)\equiv(2,3),(3,2)$.

Comment: The question had an error and has been edited.

Comment: @it'sMe i think you made a mistake could you tell me how you reached a^2 | a^3 + 1 ?